# how to make expendable side bar menu swift3

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift3, side-menu

I was trying to create a Slide side out menu using the 'SwiftySideMenu' framework but I could not do the know how to create expandable TableView. I will share you one image screenshot my requirement as it is like this image[image]

Any one Please help me.Thanks advance.

Comment: Show your code so far

Comment: i don't have any code yet because i don't know how to implement it, need help to integrate my code